# Applied for a UK visa as a family, but received status on only one applicant. Is this common?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, family, application-status, vfs-global

We applied for a standard visitor visa for the UK as a family of 4. Today I got back my passport with the Visa approved - I am the primary applicant. But we didn't get the other 3 passports. For mine also, I am yet to get an email from UKVI saying that a decision has been reached on my application. I just got a message from VFS to go and collect my passport.

At the VFS center, the lady showed me the status for the other 3 passports - it said something like "Outscan from Embassy to VFS". Mine was "Inscan at VFS" indicating it had been received.

Is this a common happening? Does it mean only their passport dispatch has been delayed and maybe arriving later in a few days?

Or could it be possible that the applications are being processed separately by different ECO's on their individual merit? I thought that a family visa application with the GWF numbers tying them together would be considered and processed as one. Is there a cause for concern with the other Visa applications?

Comment: I don't see any answerable question, here. I appreciate that visa applications are stressful and reassurance would be helpful but you'll just have to wait and see what happens.

Comment: @DavidRicherby My question is that if we apply as a family with all the applications linked by the GWF numbers of the primary, isn't there a SOP to process all these applications together and decide on them together by the same ECO? Is there a possibility that they are still treated separately and assessed at different times by different people?

Comment: @Vikky Unfortunately the inner workings of VFS are probably not within TSE users’ area of expertise. It makes sense that applications would be considered together, but it also makes sense that the primary application would be decided first since without that the others probably fail. I seem to recall a couple of questions on TSE where not all family members have been approved, but as David Richerby says your question isn’t answerable (unless you direct it to VFS itself).